# one to one relationship between classes in java

Tags: java, class, relationship

I have to implement following classes in Java SE but I cannot figure out that how can I achieve the one-to-one relationship between ATMCard and Account. I have researched (may be with wrong keywords) but could not find anything. Thank you in advance..

[image: Class diagram, mentioned in the question]

Comment: I assume this is homework, if so please tag it as such.  Also please indicate what you have tried - persumably you've created the `ATMCard` class.  Given the `ATMCard` has a one-to-one relationship with both `CustName` and `accountNo`, it shouldn't be that great a leap of imagination to see how to add the relationship to an `Account`.  If you're still unsure, you are really are best to discuss with your tutor than post here in hope of being given the answer.

Comment: Actually, this is not a homework but a part of my master thesis and I am not trying to find a source code from people but learn the logic of it, which is the aim of this site or? By the way, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I find your model a bit strange for `ATMCard` and `Account`:

- isn't the `PIN` related to the `ATMCard` rather than to the `Account`?
- isn't the `custName` related the `Account` ?

Then, the 1-1 relationship means you will have one of these:

- the `Account` class has a member of type `ATMCard`
- the `ATMCard` class has a member of type `Account`
- both above relations.
- none of the above, but getters that will fetch the related entity based on an ID. For instance, you can have a `ATMCard$getAccount()` that will retrieve the related `Account` based on the `accountNo`.

It really depends on the model logic you need.

As @NickHolt suggests, I would go for a one-way relation ship you can initialise through a factory, e.g.

```
public static ATMCard createCard(String name, int accNo, int pin, int initBal) {
   Account acc = new Account(name, accNo, initBal);
   ATMCard card = new ATMCard(pin);
   card.setAccount(acc);
   return card; 
}
```

You can have `ATMCard` and `Account` constructors protected to enforce the use of the public factory method.

Note: you can use a framework like `Spring` or `Guice` to provide this kind of *factory* and *injection* service.

Answer (score 1):

To create one to one relationship between `ATMCard` and `Account`, you have to create `Account` instance in `ATMCard` class.

Comment: In order to succeed this relationship, which is two-way, should I create ATMCard instance in Account and at the same time, Account instance in ATMCard?

Comment: You cannot do both (create account instance in card **and** the otherway around). The most flexible is certainly to have a card factory, that will create both objects through protected constructor, and setting the relation through protected setters. This way you can enforce the strong relationship between both objects.

Comment: 2 way relationships should be avoided, it makes the model brittle.  What benefit is there of an `Account` knowing about an `ATMCard`?  Simply create the `Account` inject it into the `ATMCard` when it's created making the relationship work from `ATMCard` to `Account` and it's job done.

Comment: @atishshimpi yes, but don't create `Account` in the `ATMCard`, inject one via the constructor

Answer (score 1):

The way I see this is `ATM` doesn't need to be related to `ATMCard` or the `Account`. Think about what happens you bank `ATMCard` is used in `ATM` of other bank? Or you bank doesn't allow the `ATMCard` be used in other bank `ATM`

These should part of withdrawal operation of the ATM.

You could have a bidirectional relationship from `Account` to `ATMCard`